# How to visualize feature maps of a TensorFlow Lite model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, inference, quantization

I used Keract to visualize the feature maps of a TensorFlow/Keras model.

I have applied quantization with TensorFlow Lite. I would like to visualize the feature maps generated by the TensorFlow Lite model during an inference. Do you know a way to do this?

The reason is that I don't fully understand the interaction between weights, activations and scale/zero-point coefficients. So I would like to do the inference process step by step for a quantized network.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to extract information about weights, scales and zero-point values.

**way one:**

You can also find additional information about the below code from the [TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter#get_tensor_details).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

#Load your TFLite model.
TF_LITE_MODEL_FILE_NAME = "Your_TFLite_file.tflite" 
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=TF_LITE_MODEL_FILE_NAME)

#Gives you input and output details
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

#Gives you all tensor details index-wise. you will find all the quantization_parameters here
interpreter.get_tensor_details()

#get individual tensor value. interpreter.get_tensor(give_index_number). You will find the index for individual tensor index from get_tensor_details
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
r= interpreter.get_tensor(12).astype(np.float32)
print('Tensors', r)
```

**Way two (the easy way):**

Upload your TFLite file on the [Netron Website](https://netron.app/). There you can get lots of information about your TFlite file. You can install Netron on your PC also. Here, is the [Netron git link](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) to install Netron on your PC.